# how to deploy angularjs app using webpack after uglify on heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, angularjs-directive, webpack

I need to deploy an angularjs app.

after I used webpack to uglify the production app. The below commands appeared.

The app is working fine when I run webpack-dev-server

```
Hash: 06f0e2d056b597c4e43f
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 16533ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  4.37 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
  [13] ./src/index.js 2.69 kB {0} [built]
    + 12 hidden modules

WARNING in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Side effects in initialization of unused variable $element [./~/angular/angular.js:9552,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/angular/angular.js:20263,0]
Dropping unused variable expression [./~/angular/angular.js:15347,0]
Dropping unused function includes [./~/angular/angular.js:799,0]
Dropping unused function nodesetLinkingFn [./~/angular/angular.js:10162,0]
Dropping unused function directiveLinkingFn [./~/angular/angular.js:10169,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable check [./~/markdown/lib/markdown.js:1044,0]
Dropping unused variable lines [./~/markdown/lib/markdown.js:350,0]
Dropping unused variable number_list [./~/markdown/lib/markdown.js:427,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable old_tree [./~/markdown/lib/markdown.js:705,0]
Dropping unused variable lastIndex [./~/markdown/lib/markdown.js:775,0]
Condition always false [./~/markdown/lib/markdown.js:1718,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/markdown/lib/markdown.js:1720,0]
```

But when I try to run the uglified production app, the same error keeps popping up. (See below)

the command I ran was `node ./src/bundle.js` (the output after uglified)

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:21
O=x||k;else{O=x||S,_=[];for(var V in o)Nr.call(o,V)&&"$"!==V.charAt(0)&&_.push(V)}for(w=_.length,T=new Array(w),f=0;f<w;f++)if(C=o===_?f:_[f],E=o[C],A=O(C,E,f),$[A])M=$[A],delete $[A],I[A]=M,T[f]=M;else{if(I[A])throw r(T,function(e){e&&e.scope&&($[e.id]=e)}),s("dupes","Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: {0}, Duplicate key: {1}, Duplicate value: {2}",h,A,E);T[f]={id:A,scope:void 0,clone:void 0},I[A]=!0}for(var D in $){if(M=$[D],N=pe(M.clone),i.leave(N),N[0].parentNode)for(f=0,v=N.length;f<v;f++)N[f][a]=!0;M.scope.$destroy()}for(f=0;f<w;f++)if(C=o===_?f:_[f],E=o[C],M=T[f],M.scope){g=j;do g=g.nextSibling;while(g&&g[a]);c(M)!=g&&i.move(pe(M.clone),null,j),j=l(M),u(M.scope,f,y,E,b,C,w)}else d(function(e,t){M.scope=t;var n=p.cloneNode(!1);e[e.length++]=n,i.enter(e,null,j),j=n,M.clone=e,I[M.id]=M,u(M.scope,f,y,E,b,C,w)});$=I})}}}}],Ua="ng-hide",Fa="ng-hide-animate",qa=["$animate"

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:21:8320)
    at t (C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:1:169)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:21:8704)
    at t (C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:1:169)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:22:1478)
    at t (C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:1:169)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:1:289)
    at t (C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:1:169)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:1:256
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\udemy\Website\AngularJS\Leadiq\src\bundle.js:1:261)
```

My Github repo is via this link [Github repo](https://github.com/boyboi86/Github_README_angular) can someone please assist and advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your web app can run on webpack-dev-server, as long as your code can survive uglification (uglify plugin). All you need is to set up your own mini server, to render your static/ dynamic assets.

I will explain from node.js and npm method.

IF you are deploying to heroku, you will need to use 2 scripts `postinstall` and `start`. `postinstall` basically means you will perform `webpack -p` task, production ready all your js files into a single bundled file based on your webpack.config.js. `start` will trigger the mini server to render web app.

Both commands will automatically be run on heroku once you push the codes to heroku master using `git push heroku master`. `npm run postinstall` will be run first follow by `npm start`.

DO NOT USE webpack-dev-server for any form of deployment.

Kindly refer to my github repo for more details.

[Github repo](https://github.com/boyboi86/Github_README_angular)